# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror

When I run [C3D-tensorflow](https://github.com/hx173149/C3D-tensorflow)'s 
`train_c3d_ucf101.py` from Github, there is an error in line 165 shows

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'
```

And the code in line 165 is

```
varlist1 = list( set(weights.values() + biases.values()) - set(varlist2) )
```

So can you tell me how can I do to solve this problem, the version of python I use is 3.5, with tensorflow1.4 and anaconda3.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to run a Python2 librairy with Python3.

```
varlist1 = list( set(weights.values() + biases.values()) - set(varlist2) )
```

The above line is correct in Python2 where `dict.values()` returns a `list`, but is not in Python3 where it returns a special type `dict_values`.

If you can fix this code, the following would be valid in both Python2 and Python3

```
varlist1 = list((set(weights.values()) | set(biases.values())) - set(varlist2))
```

Otherwise, you cannot use this library with Python3.

Comment: Don't forget parens. `|` has lower precedence than `-`

Comment: @MadPhysicist really good point. I did not know that one. I actually find it's a somewhat odd design choice.

Comment: It's much easier to intuit for something like `x | y - 2`, with x and y integers.

Comment: That's true! But my feeling is that using + would have made more sense than using | for set union due to priority. Any idea why that design choice?

Comment: Oh, sure. `|` goes much better as a complement to `&` than `+` does. The operations are in fact a close analogue to bitwise combinations.

Comment: The set operations of union and intersection are essentially equivalent to the logical operations of or and and.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right, the dict_values type is specific to Python3, Python2 used to return tuples!

Comment: No, it would return a list of the values.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. all these operations work fine in py2: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: NVM, totally didn't see that `set` was being used in the incorrect line.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. i see your point now. Using set operations will actually help make it more portable then

Comment: I think @juanpa.arrivillaga is totally right actually. Rereading OP's answer, it seems it is not their code! It's actually a Python2 librairy they are trying to run with Python3

Comment: Thank you very much@Olivier Melançon, I check out the project and find it's really based on python2